# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'SystemSoundID to parameter of type 'SystemSoundID'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audiotoolbox

I don't understand AudioToolbox Framework...
I have this line of code:

```
-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender{

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID1);

}
```

But xcode give me this error:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'SystemSoundID  to parameter of type 'SystemSoundID'

Xcode suggest me to do this instead:

```
-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender{

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(*(PlaySoundID1));

}
```

But if i do that, the sound doesn't play! Plus i've seen many youtube tutorials where people didn't even get an error... Is there a way to disable a certain warning in xcode or is there a way to fix this issue?

EDIT: i also get the same error on this line on code:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL1, &PlaySoundID1);
```

Xcode suggest me to take off the "&" infront of my system sound id but if i do so, the sound won't play! The only time the sound play is if i contradict xcode (i normally wouldn't mind but since i'm having over a 100 sounds, the amount of errors is ridiculous!)

[image]

Comment: Show how you defined `PlaySoundID1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you are most likely defining `PlaySoundID1` incorrectly.

You probably have something like:

```
SystemSoundID *PlaySoundID1;
```

but what you need is:

```
SystemSoundID PlaySoundID1; // no asterisk
```

Your call to `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` should be something like:

```
SystemSoundID usedSoundID;
OSStatus status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL1, &usedSoundID);
// check the status and look at usedSoundID as needed
```

The 2nd parameter is an "out" value so you should not be passing in your `PlaySoundID` value.

Comment: I indeed added the astericks... It's fixed now! Thank you for your time!